# Transforming ODE into polar form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

Let $z=\rho e^{i\phi}$ be a complex number and $\alpha$ some parameter. I determined the following ODE
$$
\dot{\rho}e^{i\phi}+i\rho\dot{\phi}e^{i\phi}=\rho e^{i\phi}(\alpha+i-\rho^2).
$$

How to get the *polar form*
$$
\dot{\rho}=\rho(\alpha-\rho^2),\qquad\dot{\phi}=1
$$
from this? I do not see it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you assume $\rho$ and $\phi$ are real (and you do), then you're given a *complex* equation for two real variables. First, you divide both sides by $e^{i \phi}$. Then, you write both sides in the form $a+b i$, yielding
\begin{equation}
 \big(\dot{\rho}\big) + i \big(\rho \dot{\phi}\big) = \big(\alpha \rho- \rho^3\big) + i \big(\rho\big).
\end{equation}
The complex number on the left hand side must equal the complex number on the right hand side, so both the real and imaginary parts must match. Therefore, you get *two* equations:
\begin{align}
 \dot{\rho} &= \alpha \rho - \rho^3, \\
 \rho \dot{\phi} &= \rho.
\end{align}
I'm sure you can take it from here.

Comment: $\dot{\rho}$ and $\dot{\phi}$ are again real-valued functions since $\rho$ and $\phi$ are?

Comment: Yep, that's right.